# python requests ChunkedEncodingError when receiving and writing some data from a server

Tags: python, python-requests, chunked-encoding

I am working on a python script (as a smaller part of a project) that would accept some URLs and receive the data sequentially using the `requests` module and write it to a file.

The thing is, I guess, that the server I am receiving from, does not handle the connection effectively. Consequently, the connection seems to get broken in the middle of the process.

For example, I was receiving a video file (~150MB) from the said server (hosted on Heroku) among some other smaller files, but while writing the video, the process ended with about just 40MB of data written **(No runtime errors so far though)**.

Here is the code snippet:

```
with open(f"./files/{filename}", 'wb') as file:
    size = 0
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        size+=len(chunk)
        print(f"{round(size/(1024*1024),3)}MB",end="\r")
        if chunk:
            file.write(chunk)
```

I tried different values for `chunk_size` like `10240`, `8192` etc. But all seemed to have the same problem and wrote unequal smaller sized files but never complete.

This was until I read the docs and tried to set `chunk_size=None`. This resulted in the following error after about 100MB of data was written:

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(109051904 bytes read, 53405476 more expected)', IncompleteRead(109051904 bytes read, 53405476 more expected))
```

I know it's obvious from the exception that the connection was broken before all the bytes could be received but I had a hard time all day trying to figure out the fix.

Also, I tried `try-except` for the above exception but that seemed to have corrupted the video as some parts of it were missing.

So, my question is, how can I make the script reconnect, or wait for the server (or my computer) to re-establish the connection to receive those missing bytes?